# Custom HTTP Module breaks relative paths.. Why and how to fix?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, https, ajaxcontroltoolkit

### Background + Original Problem (using workaround)

I have a website where I want to serve some pages as HTTP and some as HTTPS. To do this I've written a function which does the following:

```
        public static void ChangeRequestWithSecurity()
    {
        string absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"].Equals("on") && !IsSecure(absolutePath))
        {
            ErrorHandling.JustWriteToDatabase("Changing from HTTPS to HTTP: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("https://", "http://"), "DEBUG");
            //Redirect to http version
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("https://", "http://"));
        }
        else if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTPS"].Equals("on") && IsSecure(absolutePath))
        {
            ErrorHandling.JustWriteToDatabase("Changing from HTTP to HTTPS: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"), "DEBUG");
            //Redirect to https version
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
        }
        else ErrorHandling.JustWriteToDatabase("Got correct Path: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, "DEBUG");
    }
```

Currently I have this placed in the Global.asax file under the Application_BeginRequest method. Please tell me if there is a more appropriate place for this!

IsSecure is a method which looks up page names from a section of my web.config file where they are listed, and if they should be secure returns true.

```
  <SecurePages>
  <add key="/XXXX/Login.aspx" value="page" />
  <add key="/XXXX/Admin.aspx" value="page" />
  <add key="/XXXX/Test.aspx" value="page" />
  <add key="/XXXX/Scripts/ImportantScript.js" value="page" />
```

This works fine for generally browsing a website, however if I now try to do a Response.Redirect("~/TestPage.aspx");

This will break on our production environment resulting in the page being served with no HTTP OR HTTPS information:

**www.mywebsite.com/XXXX/TestPage.aspx** instead of **http://www.mywebsite.com/XXXX/TestPage.aspx**

I don't understand why this is occurring.

As a workaround for this I stopped using Response.Redirect and wrote a custom redirector, however it doesn't feel like this should be neccessary.

```
public static void RedirectWithSecurity(string newPage)
    {
        string oldAbsoluteUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        string oldUriAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments[HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1];
        string newUriStripped = oldAbsoluteUri.Remove(oldAbsoluteUri.LastIndexOf(oldUriAddress));
        string path =newUriStripped+ newPage;
        if (IsSecure(path) && path.Contains("http://")) path = path.Replace("http://", "https://");
        else if (!IsSecure(path) && path.Contains("https://")) path = path.Replace("https://", "http://");

        ErrorHandling.JustWriteToDatabase("CODE REDIRECT: FROM: " + oldAbsoluteUri + " TO: " + path, "DEBUG");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(path);
    }
```

### Current Problem, Fairly sure not as a result of workaround

So now this works perfectly for my basic pages and my redirects HOWEVER my AjaxControlToolKit components have stopped working for pages using HTTPS. By looking at the network traffic using fiddler I've noticed that WebResource.axd files are being sent over HTTP for my HTTPS pages... But can anyone tell me why?

I've found one potential solution here: http://solutionmania.com/blog/2009/8/1/automatically-switching-to-ssl-in-asp-net but it's another workaround and I'd rather understand and deal with the underlying issue.

Platforms used:
IIS 7, ASP.NET 4.5. OH and I'm using MasterPages if that is relevant. (ToolkiScriptManager is defined in Masterpage)